# Webview with UUID

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

How would I add to this the UUID or some sort of unique ID to the URL in xcode?

```
[Launch loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite.com/app/launch.php?&edit&uuid="]]];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString* uuid = [[UIDevices currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
NSString* StringUrl =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://somewebsite.com/app/launch.php?&edit&uuid=%@", udid ];

[Launch loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: StringUrl]];
```

Answer (score 0):

By UUID do you mean a unique identifier tied to the device, or just a unique GUID?

Here's a link to help you create unique UUID's or GUIDs that aren't tied to the device:

http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/09/creating-guid-or-uuid-in-objective-c.html

And, here's your code, updated to format in the device UDID:

```
NSString* udid = [[UIDevices currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];

[Launch loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://somewebsite.com/app/launch.php?&edit&uuid=%@", udid ]]];
```

Note however, that uniqueIdentifier is deprecated and Apple won't accept apps that use it.  You could instead use the identifier created by OpenUDID:  https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

Answer (score -1):

Apple doesn't allow developers to use the UDID anymore. However, they're supposedly releasing an alternative today so developers can still collect analytics data, see http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/08/apple-to-launch-new-app-usage-tracking-tools-for-developers-to-balance-user-privacy/